# Getting Cards to fit in body properly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a page where a video is playing in the hero inside of the header with the navbar. I want to scroll down to my row of cards, but when I brought my code over from another page the styling got messed up. how can I make my cards display properly under this header without messing up the styling of the header and body? I have provided a screenshot and my code. Thanks!:

The card that I want to display under my header:

[image: Stacked cards]

```js
var $card = $('.card1');
var lastCard = $(".card-list .card").length - 1;

$('.next').click(function() {
  var prependList = function() {
    if ($('.card1').hasClass('activeNow')) {
      var $slicedCard = $('.card1').slice(lastCard).removeClass('transformThis activeNow');
      $('ul').prepend($slicedCard);
    }
  }
  $('li').last().removeClass('transformPrev').addClass('transformThis').prev().addClass('activeNow');
  setTimeout(function() {
    prependList();
  }, 150);
});

$('.prev').click(function() {
  var appendToList = function() {
    if ($('.card1').hasClass('activeNow')) {
      var $slicedCard = $('.card1').slice(0, 1).addClass('transformPrev');
      $('.card-list').append($slicedCard);
    }
  }

  $('li').removeClass('transformPrev').last().addClass('activeNow').prevAll().removeClass('activeNow');
  setTimeout(function() {
    appendToList();
  }, 150);
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #E5E5E5 !important;
}

.navbar-light {
  background-color: transparent;
  z-index: 5;
}

.navbar-nav {
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.navbar-brand {
  font-size: 35px;
}

.nav-item {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  color: #ffffff !important;
}

.nav-item2 {
  background-color: #9370DB !important;
  border-radius: 15px !important;
  width: 95px !important;
  text-align: center !important;
  font-size: 20px;
}

header {
  position: relative;
  background-color: black;
  height: 75vh;
  min-height: 25rem;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

header video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 0;
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

header .container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

header .overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: 1;
}


/* Media Query for devices withi coarse pointers and no hover functionality */


/* This will use a fallback image instead of a video for devices that commonly do not support the HTML5 video element */

@media (pointer: coarse) and (hover: none) {
  header {
    background: url('https://source.unsplash.com/XT5OInaElMw/1600x900') black no-repeat center center scroll;
  }
  header video {
    display: none;
  }
}

.graybg {
  background-color: #ffffff !important;
  border-radius: 15px !important;
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 7px;
}

.searchbox {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 15px !important;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 5px;
  padding: 30px;
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 75px;
  text-align: center;
}

.search {
  position: relative;
  right: -185px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space evenly;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 15px !important;
  padding: 7px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 3px solid #000000;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.zipcode {
  position: relative;
  right: -165px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space evenly;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  width: 50%;
  border-radius: 15px !important;
  padding: 7px;
  border: 3px solid #000000;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.sortbox {
  position: relative;
  right: -75px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space evenly;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 33%;
  border-radius: 15px !important;
  padding: 7px;
  border: 3px solid #000000;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.filterbox {
  position: relative;
  right: 85px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space evenly;
  width: 30%;
  border-radius: 15px !important;
  padding: 7px;
  border: 3px solid #000000;
  font-size: 17px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.col-md-5 {
  margin: auto;
}

.card-title {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.card-text {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 800;
  margin-top: -75px;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  font-weight: bold;
}

:-moz-placeholder {
  font-weight: bold;
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {
  font-weight: bold;
}


/*---Star Rating---*/

.rating-box {
  width: 175px;
  border-radius: 15px !important;
  height: 35px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: #E5E5E5;
  border: 1px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

svg {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 3px;
  margin-top: 3px;
}


/* hide radio buttons */

input[name="star"] {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  margin-left: -2px;
}


/* hide source svg */

.star-source {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}


/* set initial color to transparent so fill is empty*/

.star {
  color: #7a7a7a;
  transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out;
}


/* set direction to row-reverse so 5th star is at the end and ~ can be used to fill all sibling stars that precede last starred element*/

.star-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  justify-content: center;
}

label:hover~label .star,
svg.star:hover,
input[name="star"]:focus~label .star,
input[name="star"]:checked~label .star {
  color: #fbff28;
}

input[name="star"]:checked+label .star {
  animation: starred 0.5s;
}

input[name="star"]:checked+label {
  animation: scaleup 1s;
}

@keyframes scaleup {
  from {
    transform: scale(1.2);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes starred {
  from {
    color: #d6ca2a;
  }
  to {
    color: #d6ca2a;
  }
}


/*---Links---*/

a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

a:visited {
  color: black;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: purple;
}


/*---Like Button---*/

.btns1 {
  position: relative;
  top: -50px;
  left: 410px;
}

.btns2 {
  position: relative;
  top: -50px;
  left: 410px;
}

.btns3 {
  position: relative;
  top: -50px;
  left: 410px;
}

.btns4 {
  position: relative;
  top: -50px;
  left: 410px;
}

.btns5 {
  position: relative;
  top: -50px;
  left: 410px;
}

.btns6 {
  position: relative;
  top: -50px;
  left: 410px;
}


/*---Card One---*/


/*---Card Body---*/

.card1 {
  position: relative;
  top: 45px;
  right: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  border: none;
  transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 20px;
  width: 420px;
  height: 330px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 12px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.card1 .card-meta {
  position: relative;
  left: -65px;
  color: #9370DB;
}

.card1 .roomB {
  position: relative;
  left: 5px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.card1 .roomC {
  position: relative;
  left: 5px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.stuLocation {
  position: relative;
  top: -10px;
  left: -65px;
}

.card1.card-has-bg {
  transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
  background-size: 130%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}

.card1.card-has-bg:hover {
  transform: scale(0.98);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  background-size: 130%;
  transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
}

.card1.card-has-bg:hover .card-img-overlay {
  transition: all 800ms cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, #d2d2d25c 100%);
}

.card1 .card-body {
  transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
}

.card1:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 800ms cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
}

.card1:hover .card-body {
  margin-top: 30px;
  transition: all 800ms cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
}

.card1 .card-img-overlay {
  background-color: rgba(138, 138, 138, 0.425);
}


/*---Card Body---*/


/*---Heart Button---*/

.btns1 {
  position: relative;
  top: -70px;
  left: 300px;
}


/*---Heart Button---*/


/*---Star Rating---*/

.rating-box {
  position: relative;
  top: -75px;
  left: -25px;
  border-radius: 15px !important;
  width: 105px;
  height: 15px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: #e5e5e55a;
  border: 1px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

svg {
  position: relative;
  top: -6px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  padding-left: 3px;
  padding-right: 3px;
}


/* hide radio buttons */

input[name="star"] {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  margin-left: -2px;
}


/* hide source svg */

.star-source {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}


/* set initial color to transparent so fill is empty*/

.star {
  color: #7a7a7a;
  transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out;
}


/* set direction to row-reverse so 5th star is at the end and ~ can be used to fill all sibling stars that precede last starred element*/

.star-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  justify-content: center;
}

label:hover~label .star,
svg.star:hover,
input[name="star"]:focus~label .star,
input[name="star"]:checked~label .star {
  color: #fbff28;
}

input[name="star"]:checked+label .star {
  animation: starred 0.5s;
}

input[name="star"]:checked+label {
  animation: scaleup 1s;
}

@keyframes scaleup {
  from {
    transform: scale(1.2);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes starred {
  from {
    color: #d6ca2a;
  }
  to {
    color: #d6ca2a;
  }
}


/*---Star Rating---*/

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .card {
    min-height: 350px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 420px) {
  .card {
    min-height: 300px;
  }
}


/*---Card stack---*/

.stucontainer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 900px;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 50px 80px;
}

.stucontainer .card1-stack {
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.stucontainer .card1-stack .buttons {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.46);
  border: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  left: 0;
  top: 55%;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 35px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 22px;
  z-index: 100;
  outline: none;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

.stucontainer .card1-stack .buttons:hover {
  transform: scale(1.3, 1.3);
}

.stucontainer .card1-stack .prev {
  left: 15px;
  right: auto;
}

.container .card1-stack .next {
  left: auto;
  right: 15px;
}

.stucontainer .card1-stack .carousel .buttons:hover {
  color: #C01313;
  background: #fff;
}

.stucontainer .card1-stack .card-list {
  width: 300px;
}

.stucontainer .card1-stack .card-list__image {
  height: 200px;
}

.stucontainer .card1-stack .card-list__text {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.stucontainer .card1-stack .card-list li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  list-style: none;
  height: 300px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 15px 1px rgba(225, 225, 225, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.stucontainer .card1-stack .card-list li:nth-child(1) {
  top: 24px;
  width: 60%;
  /* animation: scaleCard 100ms; */
}

.stucontainer .card1-stack .card-list li:nth-child(2) {
  top: 36px;
  width: 70%;
}

.stucontainer .card1-stack .card-list li:nth-child(3) {
  top: 48px;
  width: 80%;
}

.stucontainer .card1-stack .card-list li:nth-child(4) {
  top: 60px;
  width: 90%;
}

.stucontainer .card1-stack .card-list li:nth-child(5) {
  top: 72px;
  width: 100%;
}

.container .card1-stack:hover>.buttons.prev {
  display: block;
  animation: bounceInLeft 200ms;
}

.stucontainer .card1-stack:hover>.buttons.next {
  display: block;
  animation: bounceInRight 200ms;
}

.transformThis {
  animation: scaleDown 500ms;
}

.transformPrev {
  animation: scaleUp 100ms;
  display: none;
}

@keyframes scaleUp {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1.2) translateY(50px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  20% {
    transform: scale(1.15) translateY(40px);
    opacity: 0.1;
  }
  40% {
    transform: scale(1.1) translateY(30px);
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
  60% {
    transform: scale(1.05) translateY(20px);
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
  80% {
    transform: scale(1.01) translateY(10px);
    opacity: 0.8;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1) translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes scaleDown {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1) translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  20% {
    transform: scale(1.01) translateY(20px);
    opacity: 0.8;
  }
  40% {
    transform: scale(1.05) translateY(40px);
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
  60% {
    transform: scale(1.1) translateY(60px);
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
  80% {
    transform: scale(1.15) translateY(80px);
    opacity: 0.1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.2) translateY(100px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes scaleCard {
  0% {
    top: 5px;
  }
  100% {
    top: 24px;
  }
}

@keyframes bounceInLeft {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(40px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

@keyframes bounceInRight {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(-40px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}


/*---Card stack---*/


/*---Card One---*/
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" class="h-100">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="Mark Otto, Jacob Thornton, and Bootstrap contributors">
  <meta name="generator" content="Hugo 0.98.0">
  <title>StudioPick</title>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-o88AwQnZB+VDvE9tvIXrMQaPlFFSUTR+nldQm1LuPXQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <link href="./style.css" rel="stylesheet">


</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a style="font-size: 45px; color: #A388E7;" class="navbar-brand" href="#"><strong>StudioPick</strong></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" aria-curresnt="page" style="color: #ffffff;" href="index.html">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" style="color: #ffffff;" href="login.html">Log In</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item2">
              <a class="nav-link" href="signup.html">Sign Up</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- This div is  intentionally blank. It creates the transparent black overlay over the video which you can modify in the CSS -->
    <div class="overlay"></div>

    <!-- The HTML5 video element that will create the background video on the header -->
    <video playsinline="playsinline" autoplay="autoplay" muted="muted" loop="loop">
        <source src="./Joony_Vlog.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>

    <!-- The header content -->
    <div class="container h-100">
      <div class="d-flex h-100 text-center align-items-center">
        <div class="w-100">
          <div class="searchbox">
            <h1 style="font-size: 50px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif;"><strong>Find Your Next Studio</strong></h1>

            <div class="row">
              <!---Search--->
              <div class="col-md-3">
                <input class="search" type="text" placeholder="Search">
              </div>

              <!---Zipcode-->
              <div class="col-md-3">
                <input class="zipcode" type="text" placeholder="Zipcode">
              </div>

              <!---Sort----->
              <div class="col-md-3">
                <select class="sortbox">
                  <option value="Sort">Sort by</option>
                  <option value="Location">Location</option>
                  <option value="Rating">Rating</option>
                </select>
              </div>

              <!---Filter--->

              <div class="col-md-3">
                <select class="filterbox">
                  <option value="Filter">Filter</option>
                  <option value="50 mi">50 mi</option>
                  <option value="30 mi">30 mi</option>
                  <option value="25 mi">25 mi</option>
                  <option value="10 mi">10 mi</option>
                  <option value="5 mi">5 mi</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>

  <!-- Page section example for content below the video header -->
  <section class="my-5">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="stuList mx-auto">
          <!--Studio List-->
          <div class="stucontainer">
            <div class="card1-stack">
              <!---Button for scroll-->
              <a class="buttons prev" href="#">
              </a>
              <!---Button for scroll-->
              <ul class="card-list">

                <!--Studio Room 2-->
                <li class="card1 text-white card-has-bg click-col" style="background-image:url('https://images.adsttc.com/media/images/5d1b/e492/284d/d1b1/8300/00a1/large_jpg/feature_-_FFX_SDC_01.jpg?1562109025');">
                  <div class="card-img-overlay d-flex flex-column">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <div class="media">
                        <div class="media-body">
                          <h6 class="roomC mb-2"><strong>Room C</strong></h6>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <!--Studio Room 2-->

                <!--Studio Room 1-->
                <li class="card1 text-white card-has-bg click-col" style="background-image:url('https://www.unifiedmanufacturing.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/Nightbird-Recording-Studios-Pandemic.jpg');">
                  <div class="card-img-overlay d-flex flex-column">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <div class="media">
                        <div class="media-body">
                          <h6 class="roomB mb-2"><strong>Room B</strong></h6>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <!--Studio Room 1-->

                <!--Studio Front Page-->

                <!--Studio Front Page-->
                <li class="card1 text-white card-has-bg click-col" style="background-image:url('https://westlakepro.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/SnoopDoggStudio.jpg');">
                  <div class="card-img-overlay d-flex flex-column">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <div class="media">
                        <img class="mr-3 rounded-circle" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQxUXsEFPioqCqDqgp7MeLNpM7iZYL6mt97ElI3LwCnuFoarwmSWbJquoEwbi1AJSRzXBs&usqp=CAU" alt="Generic placeholder image" style="max-width:50px">
                        <div class="media-body">
                          <h6 class="card-meta mb-2"><strong>CC Studios</strong></h6>
                          <small class="stuLocation">Bethesda, MD</small>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <!--Heart Button--->
                      <div class="btns1">
                        <Button style="font-size: 35px" onclick="Toggle1()" id="btnh1" class="btn"><i
                                  class="fas fa-heart"></i></Button>
                      </div>
                      <!---Heart Button--->
                      <!---Star Rating--->
                      <div class="rating-box">
                        <div class="star-source">
                          <svg>
                                  <linearGradient x1="50%" y1="5.41294643%" x2="87.5527344%" y2="65.4921875%" id="grad">
                                    <stop stop-color="#bf209f" offset="0%"></stop>
                                    <stop stop-color="#d62a9d" offset="60%"></stop>
                                    <stop stop-color="#ED009E" offset="100%"></stop>
                                  </linearGradient>
                                  <symbol id="star" viewBox="153 89 106 108">
                                    <polygon id="star-shape" stroke="url(#grad)" stroke-width="5" fill="currentColor"
                                      points="206 162.5 176.610737 185.45085 189.356511 150.407797 158.447174 129.54915 195.713758 130.842203 206 95 216.286242 130.842203 253.552826 129.54915 222.643489 150.407797 235.389263 185.45085">
                                    </polygon>
                                  </symbol>
                                </svg>
                        </div>
                        <div class="star-container">
                          <input type="radio" name="star" id="five">
                          <label for="five">
                                  <svg class="star">
                                    <use xlink:href="#star" />
                                  </svg>
                                </label>
                          <input type="radio" name="star" id="four">
                          <label for="four">
                                  <svg class="star">
                                    <use xlink:href="#star" />
                                  </svg>
                                </label>
                          <input type="radio" name="star" id="three">
                          <label for="three">
                                  <svg class="star">
                                    <use xlink:href="#star" />
                                  </svg>
                                </label>
                          <input type="radio" name="star" id="two">
                          <label for="two">
                                  <svg class="star">
                                    <use xlink:href="#star" />
                                  </svg>
                                </label>
                          <input type="radio" name="star" id="one">
                          <label for="one">
                                  <svg class="star">
                                    <use xlink:href="#star" />
                                  </svg>
                                </label>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <!---Star Rating--->


                    </div>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <!--Studio Front Page-->


              </ul>
              <a class="buttons next" href="#">></a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!--Studio One-->

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>




  <script src="./cardstack.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: One of the problem I can see is, when you select `li` tag it is interfering with the li tag in navigation. If overlay is the problem you should change the logic behind as the whole overlay `div` is inside `li` tag

Comment: what's a good way to rewrite it?

Comment: if you want the overlay over every card then write it outside the li tag and position it relative to the cards div